# Bootstrap datatables: Can't display data in expanded row if I get data by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) for display some data. I need to make every row a collapsible and download some additional info about current row after clicking on it.

Based on [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) I've prepared this:

```
$('#tasks tbody').on('click', 'tr.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child(getToolsForUser(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
```

It's working but only if I returned static data from `getToolsForUser()`. Getting data by AJAX and returned it in `success` function throw an error in console:

> TypeError: row.child(...) is undefined

I also tried with `$.Deferred` and `done()` and the result was the same ^

Live example you can find [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dwbavnow/).

*(Comment 17th line and uncomment 19th line for make it works - but only on static data)*

How can I use ajax call in function called from `row.child().show()`?

Comment: after this line ' var row = table.row(tr);' what is 'row' value?

Comment: Here is an working example,https://jsfiddle.net/8ae3b5sz/

Comment: @Jatinpatil :O Thank you very much! Please add your comment as answer - I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to append data in success call of ajax,

```
success: function (response) {
                currentElement.child(JSON.stringify( response)).show();
            },
```

I have modified the fiddle and here it is working solution for you,
https://jsfiddle.net/8ae3b5sz/